# React - package.json after instalation by command 'create react app' and install existing package

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, create-react-app

I am new to react. I've created react application by command '**create react app**'.

In the root directory was generated files and directories e.g. package.json, node_modules.

In node_modules existed already **babel-core**, but installed it by:

```
npm install --save babel-core
```

In the **package.json** was added:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
     ...
  }
```

Earlier, there was a code based on babel without this entry.
So I cannot understand what does mean and if i will uninstall this package now if will the command delete the original library and project will be crashed. I don't know what exactly happened after installation. Can i remove this line:

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
```

will the project work?

Answer (score 0):

you can uninstall babel-core by using the command **npm uninstall babel-core** which will remove the package from node_modules and package.json file.

I think the application wont crash if you check the node_modules the pre built babel-core file will be there which was installed using create-react-app ,after you run the command **npm uninstall babel-core**